# "Select followed by First" versus "First followed by Select" when summing the data for a student

Tags: c#, comparative-review, console, linq

I am wondering which one I should choose between the following two options when I need to calculate the sum of `Data` of the student with `Id` of 1.

```
var out1 = students
            .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Sum = x.Data.SelectMany(n => n).Sum() })
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1)
            .Sum;

var out2 = students
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1)
            .Data.SelectMany(n => n)
            .Sum();
```

Any comments are welcome.

```
class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Student
        {
            Id = 1,
            Data = new List<List<int>>
            {
                new List<int>{ 1,2,3},
                new List<int>{ 4,5,6}
            }
        };

        var b = new Student
        {
            Id = 2,
            Data = new List<List<int>>
            {
                new List<int>{ 7,8,9},
                new List<int>{ 10,11,12}
            }
        };

        var c = new Student
        {
            Id = 3,
            Data = new List<List<int>>
            {
                new List<int>{ 13,14,15},
                new List<int>{ 16,17,18}
            }
        };

        var students = new List<Student> { a, b, c };

        var out1 = students
                    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Sum = x.Data.SelectMany(n => n).Sum() })
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1)
                    .Sum;

        var out2 = students
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1)
                    .Data.SelectMany(n => n)
                    .Sum();

        Console.WriteLine(out1);
        Console.WriteLine(out2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 1 will mean you calculate the sum for potentially all elements just to throw them away. You definitely shouldn't do that option. Find the student first and then sum the data.

Answer (score 4):

#### Option 1

```
students
       .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Sum = x.Data.SelectMany(n => n).Sum() })
       .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1)
       .Sum;
```

- `.Select`: Transforms all `Student` object in the collection into anonymous objects
- `.FirstOrDefault`: Finds the first anonymous object where the `Id` is matching with the predefined value
- `.Sum`: Accesses the `Sum` property of the anonymous object

  - This is error-prone since `FirstOrDefault` might return with `null` if there is no matching element in the collection
  - The fix could be `?.Sum`

So, you might need to iterate through twice of the collection (once to transform all elements then if the `Id == 1` matches with the last element). So, the order of this function is `O(2n)`.

#### Option 2

```
students
       .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1)
       .Data.SelectMany(n => n)
       .Sum();
```

- `FirstOrDefault`: Finds the first `Student` object where the `Id` is matching with the predefined value
- `.Data.SelectMany`: Flattens the nested collection of collections to a collection

  - It is error-prone since `FirstOrDefault` might return with `null`
- `.Sum()`: Aggregates the items in the flatten collection

The order of this function is `O(n)`, since `Id == 1` might find the last element.

#### Alternatives

- If you would store your `Students` in a `Dictionary` then the lookup would be `O(1)`

```
Dictionary<int, List<List<int>>> students = ...
var result = students[1].SelectMany(n => n)?.Sum();
```

- You could use two `Sum` calls instead of `SelectMany` + `Sum`

```
var result = students[1].Sum(n => n.Sum());
```

Please be aware that the indexer operator could throw `KeyNotFoundException` rather than return with `null`

Comment: "So, the order of this function is O(2n)." That's not how LINQ works.

Comment: @Johnbot Yes, you are correct. Due to the lazy evaluation it will build an expression tree and it might optimise on this when it iterates through the collection.

Comment: @Johnbot It's also possible to check the source-code in github or https://referencesource.microsoft.com, to know how does `LINQ` work. (which would give you a good idea on which approach would be feasible to the code).

Comment: @Johnbot is correct - the source collection will only be iterated once it is not `2n`.